# Are there any systems of mathematics that permit such a wide range of ways to formulate ideas

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request, philosophy-of-language

... that there is no algorithm for determining whether or not a given sequence of symbols is a wff ("well-formed formula"), but instead non-trivial proofs are required, so that some sequence of symbols thought to be meaningless could be discovered to be meaningful?

For natural language processing involving communication among people in the same language, with no machines sending their own messages, such a proof might have very little value.

For natural language processing, it may be more useful to have assistance in formulating questions designed to elicit answer messages that are more easily understood, with the combination of accumulated questions and corresponding answer messages eventually allowing the original sequence of symbols (that wasn't understood) to be edited and revised, to derive a message that is both clear and meaningful.

Comment: Already second order theories are not recursively axiomatizable, meaning there is no algorithm deciding what is or is not an axiom. If you want non-recursive syntax just identify wffs with axioms.

Comment: "If you want non-recursive syntax just identify wffs with axioms."  It seems strange that the negation of an axiom wouldn't be a wff.  What if there is a conjecture known today whose negation will one day be accepted as an axiom?  It would be strange if the conjecture were meaningless rather than false.

Comment: Offhand, I'm thinking of some fun sentences like "This statement is false," which generates annoying paradoxes while "This statement is true" is merely a tautology.

Comment: Your reaction to Conifold's suggestion makes no sense to me.  All the proposed axioms that are independent of ZF, like Choice/Determinacy and the Continuum Hypothesis are neither true nor false in ZF.  That does not make them meaningless, just undecidable. We might someday accept any one of those as an axiom, and thus increase the power of our set theory.

Comment: @jobermark "All the proposed axioms that are independent of ZF, like Choice/Determinacy and the Continuum Hypothesis are neither true nor false in ZF." --> did you mean to write "are neither provable nor disprovable in ZF"?

Comment: @jobermark --> Changing the premises in a radical way seems to me like pulling the rug out from under somebody, if you are allegedly interpreting what the person meant before you changed the premises.  Changing the rules for wffs -- on the other hand -- would not merely change the meaning of a wff, but potentially change whether or not a sequence of symbols is a meaningful conjecture.

Comment: No, I meant they are neither true nor false *In ZF*.  They may be true or false in the broader reality, but in ZF, they can be neither or both.  We can choose to assume the Axiom of Choice, or its exact opposite, so both of them are neither true nor false until we have done so.  And we have not, as yet, done so.  Please never attempt to put words in my mouth, or I will simply refuse to respond further.

Comment: Nobody is changing the premises.  I am pointing out that the options are not true, false and meaningless, which seems to be presumed in your earlier response.  They include at least the option of being neither true nor false within the system, but meaningful in some broader context.  The Axiom of choice is not true and it is not false, but it is not meaningless, it entails specific other things under specific other conditions, and that is meaning.  If we decide, for instance that Tarski's paradox really is too bad, we might choose the Axiom of Determinacy to be part of our future set theory.

Comment: @jobermark "The Axiom of choice is not true and it is not false" --> What system of logic are you using?  If I were to assert both that Goldbach's conjecture is not true and that Goldbach's conjecture is not false, then I would anticipate that others would respond with either an objection, or a question about what I meant.

Comment: And that would not be taking place within any formal mathematical system.  It would be taking place outside any given formal system, in mathematics as a whole.  But as far as the formal system of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory there are models in which the Axiom of Choice and the Continuum Hypothesis are true and others in which either or both are false.  So the *system itself* cannot consider either proposition to be either true or false.  **Which does not make them meaningless**.  The point is that not being true or false in a given system does not make something meaningless.

Comment: OK, the next time I say . **In ZF**, you can actually notice and pay attention to the fact that I am naming a given formal system, and not talking about the whole of mathematics, or you can just stop talking to me about formal systems, because you don't seem to understand what it means to work in a given formal system.

Comment: "True in a model of ZF" <-- that is not precisely the same thing as "true in ZF".  "False in a model of ZF" <---That is not precisely the same thing as "false in ZF."

Comment: @jobermark That a sequence of symbols isn't a well-formed formula doesn't necessarily mean that it is literally meaningless in the ordinary language sense of the word "meaningless."  For example, if somebody wrote a book with a more mathematical punctuation than usual, starting each sentence with an open bracket, and ending each sentence with a closed bracket followed by a conjunction symbol (except for the final sentence in the book, which isn't followed by a conjunction symbol), then a few extra closed brackets somewhere on the first page won't make the whole book incomprehensible.

Comment: No true in ZF means true in *every* model of ZF and false in ZF means false in every model of ZF.  This has been standard mathematical usage for quite some time.  So AC is *not true and not false in ZF*, it is independent of the system itself.  Also "Not well-formed" is completely different from "meaningless".

Comment: None of this is bringing your objection to Confold any closer to making sense.  Your complaint implied that in second order arithmetic everything well-formed would need to be either true, false or meaningless.  But there are statements independent of any formal arithmetic the same way there are specific statements independent of existing formal set theories.

Comment: I take it that if we start with an axiom within a given system, and negate it, then we won't find that negation of the axiom as being another axiom in the same system.  If we implement the suggestion "If you want non-recursive syntax just identify wffs with axioms", then I presume that what isn't an axiom wouldn't be a wff, and in particular the negation of an axiom wouldn't be a wff.

Comment: Also "Not well-formed" is completely different from "meaningless". <-- I cannot recall ever reading or hearing that claim before seeing it in the above comments.

Answer (score 2):

As a trivial solution to get things started, may I recommend the language consisting only of true statements?  Determining whether any statement is part of the language is precisely as difficult as proving whether the statement is true or not.  It'd be a very useful language!

Practically speaking, I believe we avoid such systems because they don't suit our needs as human beings.  But we can speak of them.  Indeed, the effort to create a sufficiently powerful language with this property is famously littered with theories beset upon by paradoxes.  Instead we tend to build our mathematical foundations on languages which are weaker and explore ideas within them.

Comment: In using the term "weaker" to describe a language, do you mean it has less expressive power than is possible?  It seems that the demand for machine-checkable meaningfulness makes for automatic semantics, so that there should be no inquiry, beyond a trivial check, about whether or not a given mathematical wff is meaningful and what it means.  In contrast, facing a poem originally written in a language you are learning, along with a translation into your first language, and notes explaining the translation, we have a task requiring assistance from human experts to help a student understand.

Comment: Are you familiar with the issues raised by Godel's Incompleteness Theorem?  His work stymed a great deal of effort to create such languages because a particularly valuable class of them was impossible.  Even in the Semantic Web, with languages like OWL, we avoid lots of very strong languages because they're troublesome to reason in. (which is why most reasoners target OWL-DL, when OWL-Full is capable of expressing more)

Comment: "we avoid lots of very strong languages because they're troublesome to reason in" --> Could you clarify what you meant by "strong" in that context?

Comment: PA (Peano Arithmetic) is strong in the sense of seeming unlikely to allow contradictions to be derived from the premises, but weak in the sense that limited apparatus is available to attempt to formulate a straightforward translation of an argument that uses generally accepted resources from a variety of branches of mathematics.

Comment: I was avoiding the particular wording because I have a bad tendency of getting little bits of it wrong, so please double check this definition: the strong systems I was refereeing to were those which are capable of proving all true statements in arithmetic (i.e. "2+2=4") and could prove all true statements about its own semantics.  That self-reference was the particularly troublesome bit.

Comment: Systems like you describe remind me of loops, really.   Loops are non-associative algebras.  That non-associativeness is so hard to work with that the typical way of analyzing them is to embed them in an associative algebra and study the loop within there.  Likewise, I think we typically choose to embed all "hard" proofs into a language which is easy to determine wellformedness, just for convenience.